# What is generating this update query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations, rails-activerecord

In my rails logs, the following (sanitized) SQL is being run on destroy:

```
 SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1  [["id", 345]]
 SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "people" SET position = (position - 1) WHERE ("people"."voter_registration_id" = 194 AND "people"."level" = 'state' AND position > 5)


class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :voter_registration, inverse_of: :people

    .
    .
    .
end
```

What could be causing the second `update` line to be created? E.g, why would it reorder the existing people (where the currently deleted persons position is 5 in the original request)?

Comment: If you share the rest of the model code and your Gemfile and we might be able to help you - but right now I can't see why that is happening.

Which controller / action  invoked the SQL code?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this happens if you're using the acts_as_list plugin

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list